# How do I convert an hg repository to git?

Tags: git, export, mercurial, github, commit

I found an open-source project which is available via hg only.

Now I want to put it onto GitHub, with my own changes alongside the previous commit history.

Hg-git allows you to use git commands to push to hg (Mercurial).

#### What allows me to push hg to git?

Comment: If you want to collaborate with said project, better use mercurial natively. Anything else will sooner or later become a headache for you, and get the others angry with the "outsider who just won't do things the civilized way". (I'm a big `git` fan myself, BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup your environment (once Python 2.7.*+Mercurial 2.2 are installed)

```
git clone http://github.com/offbytwo/git-hg
cd git-hg
git submodule update --init
cp git-hg/bin/git-hg /usr/local/bin/git-hg
cp -r git-hg/fast-export /usr/local/fast-export
```

#### Clone your hg repo

```
git-hg clone http://bitbucket.org/codeimpossible/artigo artigo-git
```

#### Push that to Github (or other git host)

```
git remote add github http://github.com/codeimposible/Artigo.git
git push github master
```

Reference: http://codeimpossible.com/2011/12/29/Moving-your-mercurial-repository-to-git/

Comment: For windows, you want to go here http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download and download the python version of the binary installer. The link will be Mercurial-2.8.1 (32-bit py2.7) or whatever the current version is. You will also need to install Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

**Side note (unrelated)**:

> Hg-git allows you to use git commands to push to hg

is wrong impression - hg-git allow **Mercurial client** interact (bidirectionally) with remote **Git-reposiory** and *can be used* (if you have Mercurial) - pull from hg + push to Git

Git (client) - Hg (repository) communication can be implemented in more Git-way with [Bridge support in git for mercurial and bazaar](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/) (**[git-remote-hg](http://github.com/felipec/git/blob/fc/remote/hg/contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-hg)** for your needs)